# Laravel - How to fix Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)

Tags: laravel, http, ssl, https

When I run,

```
php artisan serve --host=myapp.dev --port=8000
```

It starts a laravel development serve at myapp.dev:8000.

But when i open the myapp.dev link on the browser, it forces the http to https and logs invalid request (unsupported SSl request).
What do you advise me to do to resolve this?

This is the command line:

```
$ php artisan serve --host=myapp.dev --port=8000
Laravel development server started: http://myapp.dev:8000
[Mon Apr 13 22:13:58 2020] PHP 7.4.4 Development Server (http://myapp.dev:8000) started
[Mon Apr 13 22:15:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:38072 Accepted
[Mon Apr 13 22:15:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:38074 Accepted
[Mon Apr 13 22:15:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:38072 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Mon Apr 13 22:15:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:38072 Closing
[Mon Apr 13 22:15:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:38074 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
[Mon Apr 13 22:15:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:38074 Closing
[Mon Apr 13 22:15:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:38076 Accepted
[Mon Apr 13 22:15:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:38076 Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)
```

hosts file

```
cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   myapp.dev
127.0.1.1   jeremyPc

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpenx.png)

.env file

```
APP_URL=http://myapp.dev:8000
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPKlI.png)

when i open the myapp.dev link on the browser, it forces the http to https
http://myapp.dev:8000/  =>  https://myapp.dev:8000/

but, localhost:8000/ or http://localhost:8000 is still work.

Please, help me~

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uihqa.png)

Comment: In short: if you use a domain which does not belong to you `i.e. myapp.dev` you still have to deal with the policy for this domain  (`.dev` belongs to Google and they enforce HTTPS there).

Comment: In short do not use ".dev". It's best to use ".test" instead when working on projects locally

Comment: Oh~~~ I see.
I didn't know it.
Thank you for answer.

Comment: https://www.registry.google/policies/registration/dev/#!/